# Does an object with an axially symmetric inertia tensor have a "preferred" axis of rotation?

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

Imagine an object with cylindrical symmetry, such as a cylinder or cylindrical shell, where $I_{xx} = I_{yy} \neq I_{zz}$, and the Z axis is defined along the length of the cylinder shape. The object is induced to rotate by a torque which is not applied along one of the principal axes. Does the system have some sort of "preferred" or lowest energy axis that it would prefer to align along, or is it just dependent on the applied torque having a greater component along one of the principal axes?

I'm well aware of the intermediate axis theorem for an object with $I_{xx} \neq  I_{yy} \neq I_{zz}$, but even in that case, is one of the two "stable" axes preferred over the other?

To sort of answer my own question- my guess is that for an object rotating in a non-dispersive medium (vacuum, frictionless) there is no preference, but viscous torque due to drag forces under real conditions may be different when rotating along one axis compared to another. At what point would the anisotropy of the drag significantly affect which rotational axis is preferred?

Any discussion about this topic is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explorer_1#Flight

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot. One of the references in the wiki is also pretty helpful for anyone else interested: https://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/0112054.pdf